# Guide me with this stored procedure or function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Manager | Employee  |HireDate
----------------------------------------
ManagerA| EmpA      |1/1/2012
managerA| EmpB      |1/15/2012
ManagerB| Emp C     |2/1/2012
ManagerA| Emp D     |2/15/2012
ManagerB| Emp E     |2/8/2012
```

The bonus amount for each manager is calculated based on how many recruits were hired that month.
ex. each Manager gets 1000 for first hire and 500 additional for every next.

Its almost like each record has a seed

```
Manager | Employee  |HireDate   | Seed
------------------------------------------------
ManagerA| EmpA      |1/1/2012   | 1
managerA| EmpB      |1/15/2012  | 2
ManagerB| Emp C     |2/1/2012   | 1
ManagerA| Emp D     |2/15/2012  | 1
ManagerB| Emp E     |2/8/2012   | 2
```

and Bonus is a function of the seed as 1000+(seed-1)*500

I need help generating the seed .I am not sure if I should use a stored procedure to generate the seed or a function

eventually I want to generate a table as below

```
Manager | Employee  |HireDate   | Bonus
-------------------------------------------------
ManagerA| EmpA      |1/1/2012   | 1000
managerA| EmpB      |1/15/2012  | 1500
ManagerB| Emp C     |2/1/2012   | 1000
ManagerA| Emp D     |2/15/2012  | 1000
ManagerB| Emp E     |2/8/2012   | 1500
```

Comment: Using a Seed-Sequence is a very inefficient way to solve this, especially with SQL.  A better way would be to recognize the the function can also be `BONUS = (Count+1)*500`, which means that all you need is the count per manager per month.

Comment: i am not expecting to have a seed coulmn per say. its just a imaginary term i use. How do I get the count?

Comment: I was referring to it as an algorithm/approach.  Sequence-oriented algorithms are not ideal for SQL.  Answers below cover the COUNT() question.

Comment: @RBarryYoung : The seed concept is important here, since a `Count` would neglect employees hired on the exact same `HireDate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the seed

```
Select
     *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition By Manager, Year(HireDate), Month(HireDate) Order By HireDate) As Seed
From
    YourTable
```

To get the bonus directly

```
Select
     *
    ,1000 + (Seed - 1) * 500 As Bonus
From
    (
        Select
             *
            ,ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition By Manager, Year(HireDate), Month(HireDate) Order By HireDate) As Seed
        From
            YourTable
) T
```

Comment: I am liking this query. So efficient. Will try and let you know